# How to make loop wait for two input

Tags: python, loops, raw-input

I'm new to programming so take it easy on me. I'm right now working with raspberry pi and the thing I'm trying to do is, I want raspberry to wait for raw_input and input from my RFID. I have tried to put in loop between my ser.read and user_input but it have not gone so well for me.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

user1 = '0000550835'
user2 = '2345'


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400, timeout=0.5)

while True:
        string = ser.read(12)
        # Here is where i have tried to put in loop
        user_input = raw_input('password:')
        string = string[1:11]
        if (string == user1):
                print 'Welcome User1'
                GPIO.output(7,True)
                time.sleep(5)
                GPIO.output(7,False)
        if (user_input == user2):
                print 'Welcome User2'
                GPIO.output(7,True)
                time.sleep(5)
                GPIO.output(7,False)
        else:
                print 'Deny '
```

Comment: `it have not gone so well for me.` you have to be more specific

Comment: What error or issue are you receiving with your code so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python check input from console and serial at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626321/python-check-input-from-console-and-serial-at-the-same-time)

Comment: here is the thing, When i try to put it in loop it get stuck at raw_input, so i tried to put timeout on raw_input but my code  continuing to else: then go back to raw_input. So my big problem is to give time for RFID and not  continuing to if.